# Add custom object in Android

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I am trying to add a Custom object in a list. Below is my code.

```
    GridItem items[];

    if (motorList.length > 0){
        for (int item:motorList) {
            GridItem aItem = new GridItem(item,"no_image");
            items.add(aItem);
        }
    }
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a two big problems with your code:

- You didn't initialize `items` but you are trying to use it
- You can't call `.add(...)` on an array

-> You can either initialize an array with the size of `motorlist` and add the items via the index:

```
if (motorlist != null && motorlist.size() > 0) {
        GridItem[] items = new GridItem[motorlist.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < motorlist.size(); i++) {
        items[i] = new GridItem(motorlist.get(i), "no_image");
    }
}
```

Or you could create a `List` instead of an array:

```
if (motorlist != null && motorlist.size() > 0) {
    List<GridItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int item : motrolist) {
        GridItem aItem = new GridItem(item,"no_image");
        items.add(aItem);
     }
}
```

I'd recommend the second option.

Please note that both options assume that `motorlist` is a `List`